# Are there any plans for a native windows version of NodeJs?

Tags: windows, node.js

I'm wondering if anyone has any information or speculation as to when or if there will be a native windows version/port of Node.js.

Comment: No information has been provided on a native windows version of NodeJs. Let me know if you find out anything, I would be interested in working with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an ongoing effort to provide a mingw port of Node.js. Version 0.3.6+ can be [build](https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-mingw) that way.

However that is still experimental and anything but ready for more than quick and dirty development. Even in case this version matures, I suppose that it will always lag behind the *nix versions, mainly due to the fact that the event loop implementations that Node uses were originally written for those systems and APIs.

The windows version may become stable for development at some point in the future, but I hardly doubt it will ever be usable for production.

**July 2011 Update:**

> *#nodejs v0.5.1 is the first to ship with an official Windows executable. We're hoping to get some good feedback.*

Microsoft has officially gotten involved with joyent in making node.js work natively on windows.

Answer (score 2):

If one or two Windows C++ developers would put in the effort, then they could fill the gaps in the native Windows version and produce a node.js implementation that would be usable for production.

For now, there is a working Cygwin version and I don't know of any testing that shows it to be unsuitable for production. It certainly works fine (version 0.5.0pre) for development.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at:
http://www.rafaljonca.org/d/nodejs-windows

Which is based on the work of these guys here 
http://node-js.prcn.co.cc/

Both good ways of getting node on windows if you dont have cygwin.  However after many heartaches I found developing Node stuff on windows easiest by just using [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) with the [ubuntu image](http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/).

Tnx

GT

Answer (score 0):

I am strictly a Windows Dev and I have wanted to mess around with Node.js for quite a while.

It looks like Microsoft, Rackspace.com and the Node.js team are planning on working together port Node.js to Windows.

So, it's not hear yet but it should be soon. w00t!

[The Official Node.js Blog](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/06/23/porting-node-to-windows-with-microsoft%E2%80%99s-help/)

Answer (score 0):

The first stable version has been released: [Release details here](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/11/05/node-v0-6-0/).
Be sure to check for the latest version as the link above will go out of date.